# Change OS X deployment target from 10.6 to 10.5 clang error

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, deployment, clang

I am trying to change my OS X project deployment target but i keep getting this error and my build fails.

```
clang: error: -fobjc-arc is not supported on current deployment target
Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I have no clue what this means or what I have to do.

Answer (score 3):

This means you need to disable ARC in order to support MacOS 10.5. [The oldest version of MacOS that works with ARC is 10.6](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Turning off ARC might be pretty tough for a developer to do, especially depending on the size of your project, since that means you have to put in a bunch of brand new "`retain`" and "`release`" calls for potentially a boatload of objects.

Comment: Cant we change the base target and deployment target for previous versions?

Comment: Judging from the error of "`-fobjc-arc is not supported on current deployment target`", the compiler sees the developer is attempting to set the minimum deployment version to 10.5 and is objecting since ARC isn't supported there.